# Minecraft - Everyone glows when they move

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft PC server with the ip TheRulers.mcnetwork.me and whenever someone moves everyone starts glowing!

I have downloaded a plugin to set Glowing to false for an individual player, however upon any player moving everyone starts glowing again.

The command that fixes it *for about half a second* as mentioned above is `/nbt *PlayerName Glowing = False`

Comment: If someone downvotes and doesn't explain, chances are good it's because of the tooltip reason.  Asking for explanations doesn't help, and generally just leads to more.

Comment: @Frank What do you mean `because of the tooltip reason`?

Comment: Hover over the down arrow. It'll give you some direction.

Comment: @Frank I have included all of those... Good research effort: I have downloaded NBT and tried it, explaining its problems, It is clear on what I want to achieve and it is useful to people who are having the same issue as me

Comment: Its clear to you; it may not be to other readers. The point is, though, that you have a reason. Its generally not worth arguing over a single down vote; for all you know, Tim lost his keys again. Just accept and move on.

Comment: Looks like you have command block(s) giving them the glowing effect. Try to disable command blocks (`server.properties` file -> `enable-command-block=false`)... if it works you'll at least know what's causing it.

Comment: @dly Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried however the problem still continues. I believe it is only when someone moves in survival. Moving your head also causes everyone to start glowing again

Comment: There's something that ought to fix it, but that would probably hurt a bit: try deleting the `playerdata` (rename or relocate the folder to try it, don't delete it completely)

Comment: @dly Where is the `playerdata` stored? Also, would it be easier if you joined my server to limit the amount of comments in this comment section?

Comment: `server/world/playerdata` - and nope... I don't have MC installed here. :/

Comment: @dly I've gone through every world and renamed the advancements, playerdata and stats and put a 2 at the end of them. The issue still continues, even after a reboot :( Any ideas?

Comment: @Ruler Of The World this may be a dumb question, but do you have other plugins installed which could cause all players to glow?

Comment: These people seem to know what you are talking about, but are you able to include a picture?

Comment: @D-Inventor as far as a I know, no. I will delete all plugins as a last resort however **disabling them all** with plugman doesn't fix it

Comment: @PlanetAlexander I can include a picture but what's the point? It will just show players glowing

Comment: @PlanetAlexander If you want to see for yourself it might be easier to just join my server

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld exactly; if some readers see the glowing players they may be able to help because they might of seen it before. It also helps others to help you by showing what the glowing effect is. More information means more help is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long time of trying to find whatever was causing the problem, I finally decided to put all of my plugins into a separate folder where they wouldn't be run by the server. (Moving them out of the plugins folder and into `plugins/unused/`)

After restating the server (so there were no plugins running) I used PowerNBT to stop all of the online players individually from glowing

Then, I put all of the plugins back into the main plugins folder

After a second restart with all the plugins running this time, all of the players had stopped glowing, and moving etc would not cause anyone to begin glowing again

Answer (score -3):

Try removing the plugin, reloading minecraft, go back on, see if people stop glowing. If you want you can, after trying the first thing I said, doing it again but turning on the plugin this time.

Comment: By "the plugin" What plugin do you mean

Comment: I would recommend you remove this question, it is unclear and incorrect. The correct answer has been marked.

Comment: Also, you will not receive the bounty anyway, so do not keep the answer because of the bounty. **The highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded** And you have `-1`

Comment: See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty for more details